# how to build query for this scenario in Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am developing the small question-answer application in asp.net mvc 2 with c#. my scenario is this :
[image]

in my action I am having chapterId as a parameter, this field is exist in the Question Table. I want to get the all test masters objects of chapterId. one chapter can have multiple tests. where as in test mater details I am keeping the question id of that particular chapter.
how to get List here ? bu LINQ - to- sql query?

Comment: Opinion: Remove TestDetailsId, and create a composite PK over the other 2 fields, else you will end up with duplicates which I assume is not desired.

Comment: You are right, but since it is small application, and some time limits i have avoid it for now. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do it like this:

```
yourContext.Questions.Where(q => q.ChapterId == chapterId)
                     .SelectMany(q => q.TestDetails)
                     .Select(td => td.TestMaster);
```

Comment: Thanks , this is working perfect , just i Added distinct for this.as yourContext.Questions.Where(q => q.ChapterId == chapterId)
                     .SelectMany(q => q.TestDetails)
                     .Select(td => td.TestMaster).Distinct().ToList();;

Answer (score 1):

The query for getting the result will be 
            var result = (from q in questions
                         join td in testDetails on q.QuestionId equals td.QuestionId
                         join tm in testMasters on td.TestId equals tm.TestId
                         select tm).Distinct();